# Java 8 stream sum of elements

Tags: java, java-stream

```
[
  ["2016-09-22T15:56:00.05566829Z", 12223.0],
  ["2016-09-22T17:27:16.315085913Z", 10964.0]
   ]
List<List<String>> jsonValue = JsonPath.read(json, "$.results[0].series[0].values");

            Double sum = jsonValue.stream()
                    .map(list -> list.get(1))
                    .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
                    .sum();
```

I am getting array of array in json. I have to sum second element inside each array. For eg (12223.0 + 10964.0. How can I do it using java 8 streams. I have it converted to List

Comment: Streams don't parse JSON.

Comment: I have it converted to List<List<String>

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in the form `List<List<String>>`, you can get the sum like this:

```
List<List<String>> data = ...
double sum = data.stream()
        .map(list -> list.get(1))
        .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
        .sum()
```

**EDIT:** From your comments and update, I see that your lists actually contain a mixture of `String`s and `Double`s, despite it being cast as `List<String>`. What you should do instead is use `List<Object>` and cast the numeric value as you extract it:

```
List<List<Object>> jsonValue = JsonPath.read(json, "$.results[0].series[0].values");
//        ^^^^^^
Double sum = jsonValue.stream()
        .map(list -> list.get(1))
        .map(o -> (Number)o)
        .mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue)
        .sum();
```

Comment: I get this java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: @user1733735 Not possible unless you have garbage data in your lists. Update your question with the code that populates the list.

Comment: List<List<String>> jsonValue = JsonPath.read(json, "$.results[0].series[0].values");

Comment: If you prefer method references, you may use `.map(Number.class::cast).mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue)`. Otherwise, there is no reason to tear these operations apart: `.mapToDouble(o -> ((Number)o).doubleValue())`